# postgres regexp_replace negate presence of consecutive groups of chars

Tags: postgresql, regex-negation, regexp-replace

i have a database export that come with some wrong chararacter substitution(like è => e'). So i have to change it back in postgres.
I'm going crazy to make an all in one regex that catch something like this:

```
cassine' de' pecche' e'
```

it must become

```
cassinè de' pecchè è
```

(de' must not change).

I managet to get it with two pass:

```
UPDATE mytable SET comun1=UPDATE mytable SET comun1=regexp_replace(column1,'([^dnNn])(e\'')', '\1\2è', 'g');   

UPDATE mytable SET comun1=UPDATE mytable SET comun1=regexp_replace(column1,'([^\s])([dnNn])(e\'')', '\1\2è', 'g');
```

Basically i want to exclude from replace a space followed by d or n and followed by e' (like " de'") and change the e' in all other cases.
I tried `(?!\s[nNdD])(e\'')` but it still changes " de'" to " dè"

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: `(?!...)` looks forward not backward, and the lookbehind doesn't exist in postgresql regex flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace($$cassine' de' pecche' e'$$, $$(\s[^dn]?|\w\w)e'$$, '\1è', 'gi')
    regexp_replace    
----------------------
 cassinè de' pecchè è
(1 row)
```

Explanation:

```
(\s[^dn]?|\w\w)e'
 ^       ^     ^ 
 |       |     followed by e'
 |       or 2 word chars
 space optionally followed by d or n
```

Comment: perhaps could it be rewritten like this: `(\s[^dn]?|\B\w)e'`

Comment: That misses the replacement in longer words ending in e'. (e.g. cassine')

Comment: No, why? since I use the `\B` (non-word boundary anchor), `cassine'` is matched.

Comment: In PostgreSQL regex syntax, "\B is a synonym for backslash (\) to help reduce the need for backslash doubling"

Comment: You are right, it's probably because the word boundary is written in a different way with postgresql. After looking for more informations, it seems that the postgresql regex engine is build as the Henry Spencer's regex engine for TCL. So it has three different flavors (basic, extended, advanced). In the advanced syntax `\B` is replaced by `\Y`.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't an available install of postgresql, if you can test it to confirm if it works for me, you will win all my respect :).

Comment: Sorry, i will be able to test it in frew minute (once back @ work) but i guess it will work! Thanks guys!